# C# remove nulls from the end of Byte[512]

Tags: c#, arrays, null, byte, trim

What is the best way to remove the extra 00-00-00-00-00's from my byte[512]?

Currently when i load it with some data from a received packet that is not 512 bytes it returns something like

```
    Byte[] received = new Byte[512];
    int Recieving = Sockitty.ReceiveFrom(received, ref endPoint132);
    string dataReceived = BitConverter.ToString(received);
    txtReceived.AppendText(dataReceived);
    //Outputs the following
    74 68 69 73 20 69 73 20 61 
    20 74 65 73 74 00 68 65 6c 
    6c 6f 20 00 68 65 72 65 2e
    **00** 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 //This is the part that needs to be removed but the stared 00.
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00
    00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 ... and so on
```

How can i remove only to the last 00? as you can see there are 00's inside of the packet itself which i don't want to remove.

Would the best way to do it be to reverse and then loop through until it hits something other then 00 and then from then on load it into a new byte array? How would i know what size of an array to load it into?

I'm baffled. Any help appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have any info on which part is data and which part is padding.. if not.. then doing o is dangerous..

Comment: Which method are you calling to read the data?  Normally, the length of the data read is given back to you because the amount of data read could be less than the length requested.  You would then simply limit your interactions with the data to this length.

Comment: Edited OP with what I am doing to read the data.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This overload of `Socket.ReceiveFrom` returns the number of bytes read into the array; respect the contents of the array up to this length or, if you really need to, resize the array to this length.

Comment: +1 This solves the root cause. Use `Array.Copy` if you need to transfer the content to a new array of `Recieving` size.

Comment: It is the only correct way of accomplishing what E3pO desires.  Removing all zeros from the end up to the first non-zero byte will remove all trailing zeros in the data read in.

Answer (score 3):

You can look for the first non-zero value from the end, and then copy that data to a new array:

```
int len = 512;
while (len > 0 && received[len - 1] == 0) {
  len--;
}
{
byte[] cropped = new byte[len];
if (len > 0) {
  Array.Copy(received, 0, cropped, 0, len);
}
received = cropped;
```

If possible you should however try to find out what the actual size of the data is rather than looking for non-zero values. It's possible that the data would contain zero values at the end that should not be removed.

#### Edit:

The `ReceiveFrom` method returns the number of bytes that you received in the buffer, so you should use that:

```
byte[] received = new Byte[512];
int len = Sockitty.ReceiveFrom(received, ref endPoint132);
byte[] cropped = new byte[len];
Array.Copy(received, 0, cropped, 0, len);
received = cropped;
```

Comment: Your edit worked perfectly. This will be marked as the correct answer. Also thanks @Peter Huene and everyone else that answered this question.

Answer (score 3):

You can do it simply by linq:

```
received = received.Reverse().SkipWhile(x => x == 0).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Because your input size is small there is no performance issue, except you have too many call to this in small time (in this case you can iterate array normally). but I think your receive is more time consuming than this part of code.

**Edit:** For your comment case do:

```
received = received.Reverse()
          .SkipWhile((x,i) => x == 0 && received[512 - i - 2] == 0).Reverse().ToArray();
```

Comment: There is no .Reverse() for a byte[]

Comment: @E3pO: There is if you're using .NET 3.5 and have a using directive for `System.Linq`. This is a LINQ-based solution, basically.

Comment: Works perfect.. Now how can i add one last 00 to the end?

Comment: @E3pO, if you have no 00 steal you want add it?

Comment: My packet seems to fail because it needs to have an ending 00. This replaces everything down including the needed 00.

Comment: This solution is nice.  Simple, elegant and efficient.  Thanks!

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Yes it worked perfectly.  I was having trouble with a PDF file not showing up in the Telerik PDF Viewer and null bytes on the end of the file where the reason.  By putting in your fix above it solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] buf;

...

int length;
for(length = buf.length -1; i--; (i>=0) && buf[length] == 0)
    continue;

byte[] cleanData = new byte[++length];
Array.Copy(buf, 0, cleanData, 0, length);
```

Comment: That will create an array that is one byte too short, it will always cut off one byte of the non-zero data.

Answer (score 0):

```
byte[] getclear()
{
    int length = 512;
    int first_nonzero_reversed = 0;
    byte[] received = new byte[length];
    //get data
    for (int i = length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    {
        if (received[i] != 0)
        {
            first_nonzero_reversed = i;
            break;
        }
    }
    byte[] target = new byte[first_nonzero_reversed + 1];
    Array.Copy(received, target, target.Length);
    return target;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For ***removing any null value of data byte array***, You should *convert byte array to string* and replace ***null`("\0")`*** value with `String.Empty` or any characters.

```
txtResult.AppendText(System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(byteArray).Replace("\0", string.Empty);
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).